# Amazon Alexa: How to replace AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

For some reason the AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent cannot be used anymore when using the new dialog directives [1]

What is the recommended way to replace them?

[1] https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/dialog-interface-reference#dialog-reqs

Comment: The new dialog manager is not mandatory. I found out that rolling my own as a finite state machine is more flexible.